# How to keep image aspect ratio inside a %width div?

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm sorry to ask this again, but my search has not revealed anything that I have been able to implement. I have an image inside a div with the following styles:

```
<div class="thumb grid_6">
    <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="flavin" />
</div>

.grid_6 { width: 50%; }

.thumb img {
display: block;
max-width:100%;
max-height: 100px;
width:100%;
```

I'd like the image height to be locked at 100px, with the width remaining at 50%. Ideally the image would keep its aspect ratio, and just crop to the required size to fit the thumbnail. I'd rather not get into js, unless there is a much easier way to do it using js. I apologize for my lack of experience in coding.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is the image supposed to stay at a height of 100px, a width of 50% *and* maintain its aspect ratio?

Comment: @oGeez He states it in the question. The image should crop.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks @CeejeeB

Comment: Like this: http://imgur.com/N5xfhRs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/WxhjQ/4/)**

CSS:

```
.grid_6 {
    width: 50%;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.thumb img {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Ah! Fantastic! Thank you very much. Never thought of defining the width in the grid_6 class. Thank you for your answer. Do you also know how I would go about centering the image inside the div?

Comment: @user3379832 glad I could help. If you need to verticaly align the image it is very difficult with CSS and I don't know the solution, you could ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
.grid_6 {overflow: hidden; }
.thumb img {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the image shrinks to whatever width keeps the aspect ratio at height:100px. I'd like the image to cover the full width of the container, which is 50% of the body.